# Stuck with List<>

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
public class accounts
{
    private string mName;
    private string mEmail;
    private string mAddress;

    public accounts(string Name,
    string Email,
    string Address)
    {
        this.mName = Name;
        this.mEmail = Email;
        this.mAddress = Address;
    }
}
```

then, somewhere else, I create this:

```
private static List<accounts> mlocalaccountList = new List<accounts>()
```

then I fill it like this:

```
mlocalaccountList.Add(new accounts("John Smith","johnsmith@mail.com","CA USA"));
```

Now, everything is OK, except, how can I access the list<> items??

Comment: Also, per Framework Design Guidelines, your class name should be singular (since it's storing information about ONE account), and it should be pascal-case like "Account". This also means that your private static list could be "accounts". So when you do your foreach, you can do foreach(Account account in accounts) - which is a common, and intiutive way to write that. Likewise, your private strings should just be camel cased like "name", "email", and "address", with no "m" prefix. Hope that helps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access them in a foreach loop:

```
foreach (var item in mlocalaccountList) {
  ...
}
```

however, since all members are private you cannot access them at all. Consider making properties for the private members or making them public.

You can also access them by index:

```
mlocalaccountList[0]
```

is the first item in the list.

Answer (score 4):

By indexer like an array

```
mlocalaccountList[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (accounts a in mlocalaccountList) { /* do something */ }
```

will iterate through the list.

Answer (score 2):

Try `mlocalaccountList[0]` or

```
foreach (accounts acct in mlocalaccountList)
{
    // Do something with acct
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a `foreach` statement or just access by using an `index` variable `mlocalaccount[index]`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over them:

```
foreach (var item in mlocalaccountList)
{
    // do stuff with item
}
```

You can use LINQ:

```
var usaItems = mlocalaccountList.Where(a => a.Address.Contains("USA"));
   // assuming you implement a public property for Address
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the [`List<T>` MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). The [Members page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hw1as6.aspx) lists all the methods and properties that you have available. You can find help on [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) for example.

The MSDN library (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/) is an invaluable source of information on the classes and their members.

Answer (score 1):

Just combining the list of everyone's answers here so far:

1. Use an indexer into the list: `mlocalaccountsList[i]` will return the i'th element (0-based index, of course)
2. Iterate over the list using a loop.  `foreach(var account in mlocalaccountList)` will easily provide you with each element in turn.
3. Use a LINQ query to filter out a specific element in the list.  LINQ has two different styles of writing queries:

   ```
   var result = mlocalaccountList.Where(a => a.Name == "John Smith"))
   // or
   var result = from a in mlocalaccountList
            where a.Name == "John Smith"
            select a;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach statement:

```
foreach (accounts acc in mlocalaccountList)
{
 ... do something with acc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't program in C#, I believe it is: `mlocalaccountList[index]` where index is an int.